# Replace a specified char with regex that maches array of chars in a string

Tags: regex, wildcard, asterisk

so i have regex expression that finds only even number of escape chars and an asterisk :`(\\\\)+([*])`. The problem is it doesn't select the first asterisk and it selects all lines (i need that regex would try to "count" all escape chars in a line continuously, select lines that have even number of escapes and replace asterisk to percent char.

For the sake of clarity i will add a photo showing what my task is that i am trying to achieve.
https://postimg.org/image/b51v5qhkz/

Comment: Try [`^([^\\]*(?:\\\\)*)\*`](https://regex101.com/r/wK1xA7/2) and replace with `$1%`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest anchoring the match at the start of the string with `^`, then match any symbols other than `\` and then match zero or more sequences of double `\`, capturing all that  into a group, up to the asterisk.

```
^([^\\]*(?:\\\\)*)\*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wK1xA7/2) (note that the `\n` in the demo is added for the demo purposes as the input is a multiline string. If you have separate strings to handle, you do not need that `\n` inside `[^\\]`).

*Breakdown*:

- `^` - start of string
- `([^\\]*(?:\\\\)*)` - Group 1 capturing

  - `[^\\]*` - 0+ chars other than `\`
  - `(?:\\\\)*` - 0+ sequences of `\\`
- `\*` - a literal asterisk.

The replacement is `$1%`, where the `$1` backreference retrieves the text captured with Group 1.